# Desktop browse does not work in java for Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, desktop-application

```
desktop = Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

The above code does not work in the Ubuntu OS. If I execute this code, then my application gets struck and hangs for a while and during that time I cannot stop the running application in java console. The only way am able to close that application is by **FORCE QUIT**.

Comment: Does Desktop.isDesktopSupported() return true?

Comment: And what about: Desktop.isSupported(Action.BROWSE)?

Comment: Desktop.isDesktopSupported()  Returning True and  same problem existing by using only  Desktop.isSupported(Action.BROWSE) @Puce

Answer (score 2):

There are several threads on this issue. I have the same hangs on Ubuntu 16.04. I have posted here the workaround that I'm using: [Desktop.getDesktop().browse Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879854/desktop-getdesktop-browse-hangs/55122871#55122871)

Answer (score 1):

This API depends on the gnome library, you need to have gnome libraries installed for this to work.

Something similar `sudo apt-get install libgnome` should do the trick i think (do not have my ubuntu desktop at hand to check the package name, try `apt-cache search libgnome` to find the real name if this does not work).

Note : you should specify which JVM you are using, I assume it's oracle JVM.

You could also give [browserlaunch2](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/)  a try, yet it's rather old and I've never used it myself. As written on it's website it is meant to open the default browser on the supplied url :

> BrowserLauncher2, a continuation of the BrowserLauncher project, is a library that facilitates opening a browser from a Java application and directing the browser to a supplied url. In most cases the browser opened will be the user's default browser.

```
BrowserLauncher launcher = new BrowserLauncher();
launcher.openURLinBrowser("http://www.google.com");
```

As BrowserLauncher2 is open source, you could also have a look at how it detects the default browser.

Comment: yes am using Oracle JVM  Java 8 b-129 which is the latest version

Comment: Have you tried to install the lib ? It should work with it installed

Comment: yes Still it does not Working.. is there anyother suggestion

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it hangs then. You could try browserlaunch2.