# Desktop.isDesktopSupported() crashes in jar

Tags: java, crash, jvm, desktop

I have a code snippet that is part of my eclipse plugin. When testing it in a runtime eclipse version (That means it is not packed into a jar afaik) it runs just fine.
However if I pack my plugin into a jar and then run the respective code snippet it results in a complete crash of eclipse without any error logs (I'm assuming that it even crashes the JVM).

I'm running this on Linux Mint.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879854/desktop-getdesktop-browse-hangs) the Desktop API is broken in older Java versions but it should be fixed in Java 8.
Has anyone an idea why this is still happening?

Comment: Well, a library shouldn’t crash, but generally, it seems to be a contradiction to develop an Eclipse plugin using AWT instead of SWT.

Comment: My problem is that I haven't found another way to open a web page with the default browser...

Comment: Since Eclipse can do that, I’m quite sure that its API supports this…

Comment: Yes you were right. There is an API for that... I just had to explicitly search for one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not an answer to the question `why` the Desktop API breaks down when used inside a jar file, I want to point out an alternative that I have found (thanks to @Holger) for my case (working with the eclipse APIs):

You can simply use `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser().openURL(<YourURL>);` in order to open the given URL in the system's default browser.